# jQuery get value from hidden field onclick and add value to another textfield

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

HTML:

```html
From: <input id="from" name="from" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
To: <input id="to" name="to" type="text" class="form-control input-md">

<input type="text" name="fromHidden" value="">
<input type="text" name="toHidden" value="">
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#from').click(function() {
            var input = $( '#from input').val();
            $("#fromHidden").attr("value", input);
        });

        $('#to').click(function() {
            var input = $( "#to").val();
            $("#fromTo").val(input);
        });

    }); 

</script>
```

I want to get the values from the HTML input fields, `'to'` and `'from'`, and add them to the hidden text fields `'toHidden'` and `'fromHidden'`. This is to be done at any time the 'to' and 'from' are changed.

The jQuery I have wrote isn't currently working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `$('#from').val()` instead of `$('#from input').val()` or simply `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `attribute selector for name` to get the named tags.

```
$('#from,#to').change(function () {
    $("[name=fromHidden]").val($('#from').val());
    $("[name=toHidden]").val($('#to').val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#from').blur(function() {
            var input = $( '#from').val();
            $("input[name=fromHidden]").val(input);
        });

        $('#to').blur(function() {
            var input = $( "#to").val();
            $("input[name=toHidden]").val(input);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the values on change then use following script

```
$('.form-control').on('input propertychanged', function () {
    var input = $(this).val();
    $('[name=' + this.id + 'Hidden]').val(input);
});
```